# Limit Jscrollpanes width to Parents width when dynamically adding content

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Hey i am new to this

I want dynamic content  to be as wide as the parent window(and automatically resize with its width) but able to scroll down if needed(if content exceeds available space).

I am adding and removing multiple things like `Jpanel` or `JinternalFrame` to a `JScrollPanel`.

Most things whether custom classes or layout manager i tried, either only hid the scrollbar( but did not prevent content being added in horizontal direction forever) 
or did only shrink the content.

i tried https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/
but it only stretches or shrinks

```
public class MainView extends JFrame {

    private ScrollablePanel contentPane;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
...
```

in the constructor:

```
...
contentPane = new ScrollablePanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setScrollableWidth(ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.NONE);
    contentPane.setScrollableHeight(ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.NONE);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentPane);
        setContentPane(scrollPane);
```

different Sizehints or Layouts like default Flowlayout are either worse or same

the vertical scrolling works as expected but not limiting content in Horizontal direction(and it seems i am not allowed to add screenshots)
i dont need this classes,if you think it can be implemented otherwise

Comment: What is your _dynamic content_? Is it text? Is it an image? Something else? Perhaps you can put together a [mcve] and post it?

Comment: at the moment Jinternal frames that are opened from File and discarded if not longer needed. when i get to it i post an mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago, and was able to solve it with a custom JPanel:

```
/**
 * A panel that can be used in a JScrollPane which always adapts to the
 * width of the JScrollPane (so only vertical scrolling will happen).
 */
public class ParentWidthPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(final Rectangle visibleRect, final int orientation, final int direction) {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(final Rectangle visibleRect, final int orientation, final int direction) {
        return 15;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
    if (getParent() instanceof JViewport) {
       return ((getParent()).getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height);
    }
    return false;
    }

}
```

The main point is having the method `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` to return `true`.

Comment: uhm could you please specify how to use it? instead of scrollablePanel? inside?

Comment: it is to be used inside a `JScrollPane` to host other content, e.g. to build a scrollable list of JPanels that adapt their width.

Comment: ok it arranges them now within parents width like i wanted.Thank you. But something weird happens: the vertical scrollbar only appears when the main window is smaller than the first row of content. Even if i make them always appear conten behind first row is not visible. (And if content exceeds Display size) i cant scroll down. Maybe unrelated so ill keep tinkering

Comment: about the scrollbar: isn't that dependent on the operating system? I think there are some settings that will make scrollbars to appear only if they are actually necessary, but hidden when nothing can be scrolled.